# Outputting PHP Error Messages to Command Line

Tags: php

Where would I modify PHP or my script so that PHP errors are printed to the console in the event of an error? I can check my error log, but frequently a script I write will fail silently, and I won't know that it has unless I check the log.

This can be a problem when, for example, generating a result set where many of the results aren't being generated because the script is failing.

Would I put something in my script, something like this:

```
error_reporting($value);
```

Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: you cant print php to a console, you can either log them or print em on page.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to setting `error_reporting()`, you *may* need to enable [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

[Read the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to pass the proper value for your version of PHP. **Do not** leave this on in production.